# retrieve inheritance relationship information in python

Tags: python, inheritance

Say I have the following inheritance relationship.

```
object->Car->SUV
```

`object` is the father of  `Car` and `Car` is the father of the `SUV`.

How can I use Python programs to get such relationship information,like use `dir` to get the attributes of a class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `__bases__`:

```
In [11]: SUV.__bases__
Out[11]: (<class '__main__.Car'>,)

In [12]: Car.__bases__
Out[12]: (<type 'object'>,)
```

If the purpose is to call the parent method from a child method, use [`super()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super) instead.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to `__bases__` which aix mentioned, there is also `__mro__` which will tell you *all* the classes you're inheriting from, back to `object`, and the order in which they will be searched for a given attribute.

```
class foo(object):
   pass

class bar(foo):
   pass

print bar.__mro__
>>> (<class '__main__.bar'>, <class '__main__.foo'>, <type 'object'>)
```

If you have an instance, rather than a class, you can do `type(x).__mro__`.